# Is a "Tale" less factual than a "Story"?

Tags: word-usage, connotation

I am preparing a press release, and so far the headline of the press release is:

> A SOVIET LABOR CAMP SURVIVOR’S TALE

A colleague called the word "tale" into question, since this is a book about a person's actual experiences in a Soviet labor camp.  She feels that "tale" would be more appropriate for something fictional, whereas "story" should be used in this case.  I'm not so sure "tale" is less appropriate for the situation, and on top of that, it sounds better.

Anyone have any good reasons for believing "story" is better than "tale"?

Comment: I have a connotation that your colleague is correct. When I think of tale I think of fiction. THE STORY OF A SOVIET... sounds more factual to me. Having said that I don't know the reasoning behind this, just a hunch.

Comment: You might avoid the problem with tale and story by using report.

Comment: @rogermue the term *report* is awful, a "survivor" is not the same as a journalist.

Comment: Purely canvassing opinions: yes, "tale" is much more fictional / Disney than "story".  I would have certainly said that for any serious issue, "don't use tale, use story".

Comment: @JoeBlow, not just canvassing opinions - looking for a good reason to go with one in preference to the other.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist -- quite right. hopefully you find a good reference!  btw sometimes you can also use "history" for an even more serious sound: so perhaps: "The history of one Soviet camp survivor."

Comment: "Tale" implies more informality than "story", but either can imply fabrication.  It's more context than anything.  In a headline "tale" helps to suggest that the article is written based on an oral exposition by the subject, whereas "story" would be more appropriate for an article based on 3rd-party info.

Comment: you could also use "survivor's account"

Comment: I'm rather shocked that in none of the answers has anyone brought up "The Canterbury Tales", certainly an early and famous use of the word -- and one in which "tale" is used to connote fiction.

Comment: People tell their stories. Not their tales. That said, I can think of many recent stories in the news that sound like tales....No journalist would not want to be responsible for tales, though Fox News is always telling tales (that means lies by the way).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. There indeed is a contra-factual connotation to *tale* – perhaps due to its long-standing collocation and association with fictious narrative. *cf.* "fisherman's tale."
2. The ODO has as one of the definitions of *[story](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/story)* as:

   > **3** An account of **past events in someone’s life** or in the development of something: *the story of modern farming the film is based on a true story*
   >  
   >     **3.1** A particular person’s **representation of the facts** of a matter: *during police interviews, Harper changed his story* [emphasis added]

which is not in the definition of *[tale](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tale):*

> **1A** fictitious or true narrative or story, especially one that is imaginatively recounted
>     **1.1** A lie.

A story can be false but a tale seldom true, it seems.

What we have here is therefore, a **story**, not a tale.

Comment: Yeah. Logically I find tale and story to be synonymous. On pure gut instinct a tale sounds less likely to be true. "Tall tale" is the first thing that pops into my mind.

Comment: 'Tale' could also be used simply to give the title a more whimsical tone which implies age. Talking about 'A tale' or 'A story' is also very different than talking about 'The Tale of a Traveler' or 'Story of the Survivor', neither of which give a clear indication of whether or not the story/tale is fictional. It can, like in my examples, be no more than alliteration.

Comment: The word "tale" immediately brings to mind "fairy tale", fictitious. I'd say it's connotation has relations to that

Comment: Perhaps *tale* is essentially the Germanic version of the Latin *story*, and perhaps their connotations differ because words with Latin roots has a certain cachet in English (pun intended). But the definition above does fit with the roots: a *story* is a "history" while a *tale* is simply "something told".

Answer (score 7):

Offhand, I would have thought that *tale* carried a connotation of a story with a moral (fictional) whereas *story* related an event. However "survivor's *story* of the holocaust" gets about 185,000 results on googling, whereas "survivor's *tale* of the holocaust" gets about 400,000 results. (Some of that reflects on a book with that title.) "true story" holocaust: 842,000 hits; "true tale" holocaust: 298,000.

The dictionary definition doesn't help much.

Words associated with *tale* which imply falsehood include *tall tale*, *folk tale*, *fairy tale*, whereas *cock-and-bull story* implies a false story, but a *sob story* can be true or false.

I am the world's worst ngram user but here's one anyway:

[image]

I can't give you a solid reason for it, but I think *story* is probably more associated with truth than *tale* is.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the OP can use either *true story* or *tale* in his headline.

An example of how *tale* can be used effectively in a title is *[A Tale of Two Cities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Tale_of_Two_Cities)* by Charles Dickens. It is set in London and Paris before and during the French Revolution, it has a story-like edge to it and we expect to read a recount with a beginning, a middle and an end. In Dicken's novel, the word *tale* has an *epic* flavour to it. If I were to read the following title "A Survivor's Tale", I would imagine the description of a person's long and arduous journey through life. An existence of strife and struggle punctuated with episodes of great despair but ultimately, a story of great resilience and hope.

In the end, it depends on the story being told and *how* it is told. If it relates a series of factual events as in a documentary, then I would choose the expression *true story*. If the recount is told as if it were a novel, then I wouldn't have any objections with the term *tale*.

**EDIT**

Because many answers are based only on the term *tale* without considering the OP's original headline, I defy anyone who reads the following to believe it is a short story about fairies, elves, goblins, or fishermen adventures.

***A SOVIET LABOR CAMP SURVIVOR’S TALE***

The following are all examples containing the term *tale* for non-fictional narrative purposes.

- [10 Epic Tales Of Survival Against All Odds](http://listverse.com/2014/07/08/10-epic-tales-of-survival-against-all-odds/)
- [10 Astonishing Desert Survival Tales](http://listverse.com/2014/01/16/10-astonishing-desert-survival-tales/)
- [Castaway: Shipwrecked man makes land 'after 16 months adrift'](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/australiaandthepacific/marshallislands/10609011/Castaway-Shipwrecked-man-makes-land-after-16-months-adrift.html)

> An emaciated man survived 16 months adrift at sea, eating turtles,
>   birds and fish and drinking turtle blood, having floated up to 8,000
>   miles from Mexico to a remote Pacific atoll, it was claimed on Friday.
>   A Norwegian researcher said that the man – who only speaks Spanish and
>   has a long beard – was not in a good condition after his 24-foot
>   fibreglass boat washed up on the reef at Ebon Atoll.
>
> If confirmed, the feat would be **an unbelievable tale of survival**,
>   reminiscent of the Tom Hanks film Cast Away or perhaps Ang Lee's
>   adaptation of Life of Pi.

- [Poon Lim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poon_Lim) was a Chinese sailor man who survived 133 days alone in the South Atlantic after the British merchant ship he was serving in was sunk by German marines on November 23, 1942

> King George VI bestowed a British Empire Medal (BEM) on him, and the
>   **Royal Navy incorporated his tale into manuals of survival techniques**.
>   [...] The writer Alfred
>   Bester later stated that Poon Lim's ordeal was used in his novel *The
>   Stars My Destination*, which opens with a man stranded in space.

And for fictional purposes

- *[Wilderness Survival Tales](http://www.carrmclean.com/CategoryGroupBrowser.aspx?CategoryID=612&GroupNo=5150)* by Gary Paulsen

> Thirteen-year-old Brian Robeson learned to survive alone in the
>   Canadian wilderness, armed only with his hatchet. Finally, as millions
>   of readers know, he was rescued at the end of the summer. But what if
>   Brian hadn’t been rescued? What if he had been left to face his
>   deadliest enemy—winter? Author, Gary Paulsen, three-time Newbery Honor
>   winner, raises the stakes for survival in this riveting and inspiring
>   story as one boy confronts the ultimate test and the ultimate
>   adventure.

Comment: I don't think tales are necessarily epic: fairy tales tend to be quite short, for example.

Comment: @DavidRicherby valid observation, but would you classify Dicken's story as being "short" because we associate short stories with the expression *fairy tales*? The term *tale* has wider usage. If we look at Kris's cited definition: *tale* 1A fictitious or **true narrative** or story, especially one that is **imaginatively recounted**.

Comment: You claimed that "tale" implies epic. I am pointing out that this is not the case, since some tales are epic and some are not. I am not claiming that tales are always short; I'm just pointing out they're not necessarily epic.

Comment: @DavidRicherby  I said it *has an epic flavour*, and you said *tales tend to be short*, we agree that *tale* can imply both things. I also said your observation was valid!

Comment: Here is an example of how *tale* can be used to talk about one's life [Life on the Line: One Woman's Tale of Work, Sweat, and Survival](http://www.amazon.com/Life-Line-Womans-Sweat-Survival/dp/0385489781)

Answer (score 1):

*Tale* might evoke associations with the established terms *fairy tale* or *tall tale* and *tale-bearer* that are undesirable in this context, because they could appear to call into question the truthfulness of (and possibly the motivations behind) the survivor's account of his experiences.

Answer (score 1):

The [etymology of "tale"](https://www.google.com/search?q=etymology+tale) is that it is "something told".

So a tale is, specifically, a kind of story which is (or was) 'told' out loud, orally: so a "bed-time story" might be a tale (because it's 'told' to children); in the labour camp survivor's "tale" we're to imagine that the survivor "told" the story, in person, or to a witness, or that they "lived to tell their story".

Whereas "story" is from "history", which implies something more written, perhaps more factual, probably a less personal narrative.